# layout_weight and layout_width = 0dp in a linearlayout create an unexpected layout

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

i tried to put two buttons with the same size in linearlayout. my problem is that the left button isn't at the same height than the right one.

i searched for an answer but i didn't find anything related to my problem.

here a picture of what i get on an android 2.1 device:
http://tinypic.com/r/eskb4n/5

i used this code:
`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/take_pic_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/take_pic" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/from_gallery_btn"
        android:text="@string/from_gallery"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>`
```

thanks for your help!

EDIT: i used 0dp for layout_width instead of fill_parent..

Comment: i tried to create two buttons next to each other that have the same size and use all available space

Comment: LadaRaider your answer didn't solve the problem. but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the android:layout_height="fill_parent" to both buttons.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possible solutions:

1) set fixed android:layout_height so both buttons will definitely take equal vertical space.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="bottom">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/take_pic_btn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/take_pic" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/from_gallery_btn"
    android:text="@string/from_gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

2) force text on button to take single line only.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="bottom">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/take_pic_btn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:maxLines="1" 
    android:text="@string/take_pic" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/from_gallery_btn"
    android:text="@string/from_gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:maxLines="1"
    />
```